# Inserting string variables into print in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I know of two ways to format a string:

1. `print 'Hi {}'.format(name)`
2. `print 'Hi %s' % name`

What are the relative dis/advantages of using either?

I also know both can efficiently handle multiple parameters like

```
print 'Hi %s you have %d cars' % (name, num_cars)
```

and

```
print 'Hi {0} and {1}'.format('Nick', 'Joe')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: There's yet another way to do this that may interest you which is using the [`string.Template`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=template#string.Template) class. I find the syntax more readable than plain `%` formating and most of `format`'s. Since it's a class you can derive your own specialized subclasses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really any difference between the two string formatting solutions.

`{}` is usually referred to as "new-style" and `%s` is ["old string formatting"](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting), but [old style formatting isn't going away any time soon](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Status-regarding-Old-vs-Advanced-String-Formating-td4503327.html).

The new style formatting isn't supported everywhere yet though:

```
logger.debug("Message %s", 123)  # Works
logger.debug("Message {}", 123)  # Does not work.
```

---

Nevertheless, I'd recommend using `.format`. It's more feature-complete, but there is not a huge difference anyway.

It's mostly a question of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "old-style" so I can recursively build strings with strings. Consider...

```
'%s%s%s'
```

...this represents any possible string combination you can have. When I'm building an output string of N size inputs, the above lets me recursively go down each root and return up.

An example usage is my Search Query testing (Quality Assurance). Starting with `%s` I can make any possible query.

/.02